# Strassen's algorithm efficiency help

Tags: algorithm, performance, big-o

Hello I am trying to get the efficiency for Strassen's algorithm but need some help. 
The recurrence relation for the algorithm is the following:

```
A(n) = 7A(n/2)+18(n/2)^2, for n>1, A(1) = 0.
```

I've solved it to the point where I have

```
a(n) = 6( 7^(log base(2) n) - 4^(log base(2) n) )
```

Does this mean the efficiency of the algorithm is O( 7^log(n) ) ?

Comment: could you please explicitly state which strassen algorithm you are referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

As you've found,

```
a(n) = 6( 7^(log₂ n) - 4^(log₂ n) ),
```

where the `4^(log2 n)` can be discarded, and 6 is just a constant factor, so

```
Complexity = O(7^(log₂ n))
```

which is similar to what you get. *However*, the base 2 here is important because it affects the exponent:

```
   7^(log₂ n) = n^(log₂ 7) = n^2.80735
// 7^(log  n) = n^(log  7) = n^1.94591
// 7^(log₇ n) = n^(log₇ 7) = n
```

Answer (score 0):

I got

A(n) = O(n^(15/4))

recheck later.